# exception when exporting to excel from grid

Tags: c#, export-to-excel

System.OverflowException: Not a legal OleAut date.
   at System.DateTime.TicksToOADate(Int64 value)

I am getting this exception when i click an integrated export to excel button on my grid

Answer (score 0):

See [DateTime.ToOADate Method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime.tooadate%28VS.71%29.aspx) and check your value